# Why does "echo a b c d e | echo" display no result?

Tags: command-line, pipe, echo

I piped one echo command into the other

```
 echo a b c d e f g h i | echo 

 echo $?
0
```

Contrary to my intuition, there was no output, however there was also no error returned. I expected, `that echo a b c d | echo`  is only an unnecessary redundant alternative to `echo a b c d` .
But it is not the case, Why were the arguments lost on their way through the pipe?

Comment: [Redirecting the content of a file to the command "echo"](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/63658)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is due to `echo` not reading from standard input.  Pipes are only useful for sending the standard output from one command to the standard input of the next command.

Since the output ef `echo a b c ...` is not consumed by the second `echo`, it is lost and there is no output from the pipe, except for the single newline from the second `echo`.

Since the last `echo` successfully outputs a blank line, the exit status is zero.

Comment: if echo does not read from standard in, how does xargs put the arguments into the second echo command:   echo a b c d e f g | xargs -n2 echo    ?

Comment: That's what xargs is paid to do. It reads items from standard input and runs the command given as argument to xargs with the collected list of items as arguments to the command. In you example, xargs reads "a b c d e f g", and runs "echo a b c d e f g".

Comment: @sharkant As Johan said. `xargs` _does_ read from standard input.

Comment: Or just use cat instead of echo in second pipe. Cat without arguments reads and copies stdin

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Or just drop tho pipe and the second command completely.

Comment: so xargs does not push the arguments into the stdin of the echo command but makes sth. different to feed echo the arguments?

Comment: @sharkant `xargs` will read from its own standard input and execute the given utility with the things that in reads as argument(s).